# How to execute a scalar user-defined function in EF

Tags: t-sql, entity-framework-4

Are scalar udfs accessible to execute with EF?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is supported, here is a quick walk through on howto do it.

Alter your EF SSDL:

```
<Function Name="AvgStudentGrade" ReturnType="decimal" Schema="dbo" >
  <Parameter Name="studentId" Mode="In" Type="int" />
</Function>
```

Add a method stub with the appropriate attributes:

```
[EdmFunction("SchoolModel.Store", "AvgStudentGrade")]
public static decimal? AvgStudentGrade(int studentId)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");
}
```

Use it:

```
var students = from s in context.People
                   where s.EnrollmentDate != null
                   select new
                   {
                       name = s.LastName,
                       avgGrade = AvgStudentGrade(s.PersonID)
                   };
```

More info and full sample at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456847(VS.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't see but the .edmx and designer files. No SSDL file available. How to find it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a table with the name MyDbSet, it can be any table you want. Then create a record with guid "test", then use the approach below to execute a ef scalar function and return the result.

```
MyDbSet
.Where(o => o.Guid == "test")
.Select(o => EF.Functions.ToTsVector(request.Keywords))
.FirstOrDefault();
```